# Is it possible to correct a zero inflated explanatory variables in a GAM?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, zero-inflation

I am trying to fit a GAM to model a presence/absence of marine mammals in function of temporal and environmental variables using MGCV (hence using binomial distribution). My 'precipitation' explanatory variable is zero inflated resulting in an weak increase of the presence probability with rainfall. This is unlikely considering the literature on the subject and the logical explanation of the phenomenon I am modelling.

Is there a way to correct for zero inflated explanatory variables (maybe in the smoothing factors)?

Should I refit my model with a different distribution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Patou, welcome to CV! If the response is presence or absence, how can the response be zero-inflated?

Comment: Hi @AlexJ, sorry for the error in the title and question, I have spent so much time searching the web for an answer that I confused my question with the answers available. I am not trying to correct my response variable but one of my **explanatory variable** (precipitation). I edited the question to correct it

Comment: Thanks @Patou. In theory it shouldn't really matter what the explanatory variable distribution is. Refitting with a different response dist probably won't help. Are you hypothesis testing, or doing exploratory modelling?

Comment: I am doing explanatory modelling. I indeed read yesterday that the distribution shouldn't matter that much and I'm starting to wonder if the problem would not originate from outliers values at the other side of my explanatory variable (maximum values). I am also planning to test with an increase k value but I don't think this will have much impact on the results